# Put call works in PostMan but not in RestSharp: Getting a bad request

Tags: c#, http, c#-4.0, postman, restsharp

I want to call an endpoint with a Put command.

**In Postman**

I can put example `https://example.com/customers/106`. I then add a body of type `application/json` (under `raw`).

When I `Put` this body to the endpoint, I get a `200 OK`.

The endpoint I use requires two custom headers and a content-type, which I have made under headers. So I add three headers: `X-AppSecretToken`, `X-AgreementGrantToken` and the `Content-Type` (`to application/json`).

**In RestSharp**

Here I use the following. The `putstr` is the exact same body I `Put` as I do in Postman:

```
 var restclient = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://example.com");
 var request = new RestRequest("/customers/" + customerId, Method.PUT);
 request.AddHeader("X-AppSecretToken", systemToken);
 request.AddHeader("X-AgreementGrantToken", userToken);
 request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
 request.AddJsonBody(putstr);
 var response = restclient.Execute(request);
```

Now, when I do this, I get the following response which is a custom error from the API I am calling:

```
"{\"message\":\"Error converting value SOME STUFF}}\\\" to type 'eco.rest.Models.Customer'. Path '', line 1, position 605.\",\"errorCode\":\"E00500\",\"developerHint\":\"The JSON payload could not be parsed. The error message should give you a good indication of where the error is located. One common reason for this error is a missing '{' or a '}' in your payload.\",\"logId\":\"123fc6fb4964a141f612ae8ae7571446\",\"httpStatusCode\":400,\"logTime\":\"2018-05-20T21:56:56\"}"
```

**How to fix?**

Normally, I'd never ask this question. If someone else asked, I would say: open Fiddler or a similar tool and see how requests are different.

I have some troubles with this, because it's HTTPS.

When I debug through my code, I simply don't see the call inside Fiddler. I also installed Charles, but also no luck. Not sure what the problem is.

However, I thought that someone who reads this can probably come up with the problem. My own assumptions are I maybe have added the headers in a wrong way, the JSON body is encoded different or similar - but I am really unsure how to move on. I hope someone can help!

Comment: Are you sure your "putstr" is not already in a JSON format which means your "AddJsonBody" converts one more time? (I mean, you will have a JSON converted in JSON, instead of an object converted in JSON)

Comment: @hugo so............ I'm official an idiot and you are of course right. Can you please provide an answer to show the world how stupid I just was? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `putstr` value seems to be a JSON value.
`AddJsonBody` will convert this JSON value into another JSON value.

You should use the original object instead of `putstr`.